# How to building React Native App using WebRtc

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, react-native

Thank you for your help in advance.

I want to make a new WebRtc mobile application for video calling using react native, i checked many articles but not getting exact information how to start. Can any person please help me and guide me the path to create an application.

```
.\gradlew /clean
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Jig\New folder\react-native-demoapp-master\react-native-demoapp-master\node_modules\react-native-webrtc\android\build.gradle' line: 30
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':WebRTCModule'.

  > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on project ':WebRTCModule'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.903 secs

Comment: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use react-native-webrtc for this - https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc

Comment: Yeah i did checked it but it is kind of confusing like which file is primary file here in this project because index.js is only having reference.

Comment: That is the package which has to be used, see this demo app which uses the react-native-webrtc https://github.com/callstats-io/react-native-demoapp

Comment: Thanks let me check and try.

Comment: This error is coming can any person help? just ran .\gradlew /clean gradle clean command it is not running.

Comment: To run DemoApp i need to setup any socket.io server as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-jitsi-meet it's actually based on webrtc. Here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-jitsi-meet

Comment: How to sent one to many conference video stream in react native using react-native-webrtc